# XML or XSD to JPA Entity using JAVA program not manual tool

Tags: java, xml, xslt, entity, pojo

I am working on a problem to read in XML data from a 3rd party service and dump them into database.

However the XML (XSD) changes overtime and to adopt to these changes we have to recreate the POJO using JAXB or HyperJAXB, MANUALY.

But I am looking for a solution where I can do that dynamically inside my application and use the POJO's on the fly.

As per my research, it seems its not possible using JAVA. EclipseLink comes close but that lead me to a problem to convert the DynamicEntity to POJO and the filed names are string.

The most feasible solution I can think of and the only option remaining is using XSLT to transform 3rd party XML to my common XML. However I would still have to maintain this XSLT.

I am okay to use other languages such as Scala, Groovy, Python etc.

Please help me if someone has done this before.

Comment: The question is unclear. If you're extracting the XML to attributes of the POJO and then mapping those attributes to database columns in JPA then whenever the schema changes you have to make changes to the DDL anyway, and you should be able to generate the POJO from the table definition.  If this is not the situation, please clarify.

Comment: The solution I opted for this is to use XSLT to transform the incoming XML into the XML I want with the attributes I want and then using JPA to map my XML.

Pros
1. My java code is no longer tied with the XSD changes 
2. My JPA layer is completely independent of the changes happening on the 3rd party data provider

Cons
1. I still have to maintain this XSLT as it is tied to the XSD changes. If something changes on which my code is dependent I have to change the XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend none of the above.

Of course you can use Java.  Serialize/deserialize as JSON using Jackson.  You can store it in either relational blobs or a NoSQL alternative like MongoDB.

Comment: We can get the feed as JSON. However the data is relational and we have to convert/enrich the data into something meaningful to send it to another 3rd party application.

Comment: I don't hear anything that can't be done with my approach.

Comment: Yes you are right however we still have to maintain POJO, the conversion layer form POJO to Entity objects.
And if the JSON changes we have to change the POJO and conversion layer.
I wanted to avoid changing the code.

Comment: I can't help you.  It sounds like your solution is unnecessarily complex; you don't understand Jackson or JSON.  EJBs and Entity are 90s technology.  REST services have passed them by.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, you may be right in saying that I may be over complicating things. I would love to explore you solution of saving the data as JSON in NoSQL database. If you can point me to an in-memory NoSQL database that may help but still we have to manage conversion layer using Dozer or some sort.